# Network Dies After VNC Connection

Tags: networking, vnc

A word of warning, this is my first time using Ubuntu Server, or Linux in general for that matter.

I enabled screen sharing via the default Screen Sharing app on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS a fresh install today, however when connecting to it via two different Mac apps (Screens and Jump Desktop) after a short while I lose network connectivity. Only after a reboot does my connectivity get restored.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the machine firewalled? is the VNC port open to the internet? if so, it may be dying under the weight of malicious authentication attempts

Comment: It is not. It plugs into a 8 port tp link switch which then goes back to a Virgin Media SuperHub 2.